# module 'aioredis' has no attribute 'create_redis'

Tags: python, aioredis

Using python 3.6.12 and aioredis 2.0.0, asyncio 3.4.3

Tried to use the snippet from the aioredis for testing pub/sub:

```
import asyncio
import aioredis


async def reader(ch):
    while (await ch.wait_message()):
        msg = await ch.get_json()
        print("Got Message:", msg)


async def main():
    pub = await aioredis.create_redis(
        'redis://:password@localhost:6379')
    sub = await aioredis.create_redis(
        'redis://:password@localhost:6379')
    res = await sub.subscribe('chan:1')
    ch1 = res[0]

    tsk = asyncio.ensure_future(reader(ch1))

    res = await pub.publish_json('chan:1', ["Hello", "world"])
    assert res == 1

    await sub.unsubscribe('chan:1')
    await tsk
    sub.close()
    pub.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

but the following error keeps popping up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_async_redis.py", line 32, in <module>
    result = loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/Users/dustinlee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.12/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 488, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "tests/test_async_redis.py", line 12, in main
    pub = await aioredis.create_redis(
AttributeError: module 'aioredis' has no attribute 'create_redis'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Probably something obvious but I'm just not seeing it. Thanks!

Comment: unrelated, but how did you find the `asyncio` version?

Comment: pip show asyncio

Comment: thanks, also it turns out version 2.0 of `aioredis`  now follows `redis-py`, so the method `create_redis` probably does not exist anymore, try https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration/#connecting-to-redis or [pubsub example](https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/#pubsub), use version less than 2 if you want the`create_redis` method to work

Comment: I see, I just realised I was reading the docs for 1.3.0 instead of 2.0. So now I won't be using Redis.subscribe right? Now the functions should be the same with Redis-py?

Comment: I dont personally use `aioredis` or even `redis` but the link from earlier mentions *"entire core and public API has been re-written to follow redis-py‘s implementation as closely as possible"* so I am guessing yes, you can refer the [redis-py docs](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as it is what `aioredis` 2.0 is supposed to follow

Comment: Gotcha, I will read up on the docs, thanks a lot!

Comment: can you upvote and accept the answer? if it helped

Comment: sure, thanks again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`aioredis` as of version *2.0* now follows the public API implementation of the library `redis-py`.

From the [`aioredis` doc page](https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration/#connecting-to-redis)

> aioredis v2.0 is now a completely compliant asyncio-native implementation of redis-py. The entire core and public API has been re-written to follow redis-py‘s implementation as closely as possible.

So the method `aioredis.create_redis` is no longer a public API you can use to establish a connection in version 2.0. Use version less than 2 if you want the `create_redis` method to work.

You can refer the new [pub sub example](https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/#pubsub).

Code copied here in case link does not work in future.

```
import asyncio
import async_timeout
import aioredis

STOPWORD = "STOP"


async def pubsub():
    redis = aioredis.Redis.from_url(
        "redis://localhost", max_connections=10, decode_responses=True
    )
    psub = redis.pubsub()

    async def reader(channel: aioredis.client.PubSub):
        while True:
            try:
                async with async_timeout.timeout(1):
                    message = await channel.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
                    if message is not None:
                        print(f"(Reader) Message Received: {message}")
                        if message["data"] == STOPWORD:
                            print("(Reader) STOP")
                            break
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                pass

    async with psub as p:
        await p.subscribe("channel:1")
        await reader(p)  # wait for reader to complete
        await p.unsubscribe("channel:1")

    # closing all open connections
    await psub.close()


async def main():
    tsk = asyncio.create_task(pubsub())

    async def publish():
        pub = aioredis.Redis.from_url("redis://localhost", decode_responses=True)
        while not tsk.done():
            # wait for clients to subscribe
            while True:
                subs = dict(await pub.pubsub_numsub("channel:1"))
                if subs["channel:1"] == 1:
                    break
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
            # publish some messages
            for msg in ["one", "two", "three"]:
                print(f"(Publisher) Publishing Message: {msg}")
                await pub.publish("channel:1", msg)
            # send stop word
            await pub.publish("channel:1", STOPWORD)
        await pub.close()

    await publish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    if "redis_version:2.6" not in os.environ.get("REDIS_VERSION", ""):
        asyncio.run(main())
```

You can maybe also refer the [`redis-py` docs](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as it is supposed to be what `aioredis` 2.0 now follows closely.